# How can I set the custom path of an AutoroutePart programmatically in a migration in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

In my `Migrations.cs` file I'm attaching an AutoroutePart to a Content Item.

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Faq", type => type
    .WithPart("AutoroutePart")    
);
```

How can I tell the AutoroutePart to use some arbitrary string + the Content Item's slug as the custom path? I know I can change the settings of fields using `.WithSetting("FieldSettings.Setting","Value")` but this doesn't seem to be an option for Parts. I also wouldn't know how to refer to the SlugToken in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be possible

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Faq", type => type
.WithPart("AutoroutePart", part => part
    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "True")
    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "False")
    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{\"Name\":\"Title\",\"Pattern\":\"{Content.Slug}\",\"Description\":\"my-faq\"}]")
    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex", "0"))));
```

Comment: I overlooked the AutorouteSettings file for some reason. Even so I wouldn't have known how to format the Pattern. Thank you!